# PHP 'if' statement in SQL array

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I am trying to place an `if` statement, including a SQL variable in the echo'ing of an SQL array like this;

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$action = 'adddb';
$data = array();
function printUsers () {
    global $db;
    $users = $db->get ("user_data
    ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC");
    if ($db->count == 0) {
        echo "<td align=center colspan=4>No users found</td>";
        return;
    }
    foreach ($users as $u) {
        echo "<tr>
            <td>{$u['user']}</td>";
        $this_user = $db->ObjectBuilder()->where("username", "{$u['user']}")->getOne('users');
        if($this_user->group > 1) {
            if($user->hasPermission('moderator')) {
                echo "<td><i>Administrator</i></td>";
            } else {
                echo "<td>{$u['IP']}</td>";
            }
        }

        echo "<td>{$u['OS']}</td>
            <td>{$u['browser']}</td>
            <td>{$u['referer']}</td>
            <td>{$u['date']}</td>
            <td>{$u['time']}</td>
        </tr>";
    }
}
```

Now, I've concluded two things wrong with this;

- It does not seem to like me placing an `if` statement there
- It clearly does not like me using the `{$u ...` variable in the statement...

I cannot seem to figure out why though, even with my PHP glasses on, this doesn't seem so wrong... (Other than the {} in the variable, but removing them doesn't make it any different)

I have absolutely no clue what would be wrong here, following the errors didn't give me much either.

Is this even possible? And if so, am I just sort-of on the right track?

**Edit**

I've tried with the following code, thanks to the comments.

```
        echo "<tr>
            <td>{$u['user']}</td>";
if(!$u['user'] == "Guest") {
$this_user = $db->ObjectBuilder()->where("username", $u['user'])->getOne('users');
    if($this_user->group > 1) {
        if($user->hasPermission('moderator')) {
            echo "<td><i>Administrator</i></td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>{$u['IP']}</td>";
        }
    }
}

            echo "<td>{$u['OS']}</td>
            <td>{$u['browser']}</td>
            <td>{$u['referer']}</td>
            <td>{$u['date']}</td>
            <td>{$u['time']}</td>
        </tr>";
```

Now *no* IP's are displayed at all.

Comment: First, in your WHERE statement, I think you just need: `where("username", $u['IP'])`. Second, why not just `var_dump($u);` so make sure you have all the data?

Comment: You do realise that variables don't need to be wrapped in double quotes or braces, so use `where("username", $u['IP'])` instead of `where("username", "{$u['IP']}")`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you, it somehow helped... I updated the post.
Now it simply doesn't display *any* IP's.

Comment: If no IPs are being shown when you call `$u['IP']`, and there are no errors, this would suggest that field contains no data.

Comment: You may want to change `if(!$u['user'] == "Guest") {` to: `if($u['user'] != "Guest") {`. The first statement would not equate as you expect. It would be like saying `if((NOT $u['user']) == "Guest")`.